# how to set class mediator value and pass it to esb

Tags: class, wso2, esb, mediator

I used class mediator via developer studio. How to pass value from class to esb. 
That means from developer studio(eclipse) to Esb.
How to pass the value ? Anyone help me ? provide me the link...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMIIW, but maybe you are looking for something like this.
Write this in your class to set the property name and value,

```
context.setProperty("property_name", property_value);
```

This way you can access the property from wso2 proxy or sequence. To access the property you can do this :

```
 <property name="property_name" expression="get-property('property_name')"/>
```

Hope this is what you mean :)

Thanks,

Comment: That is what i am expecting, thanks for your immediate response.:)